# Python Error: Cannot extract data from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have a json output (y) like this below.

```json
{
   "WebACL":{
      "Name":"aBlockKnownBadInputs-WebAcl",
      "Id":"4312a5d0-9878-4feb-a083-09d7a9cfcfbb",
      "ARN":"arn:aws:wafv2:us-east-1:100467320728:regional/webacl/aBlockKnownBadInputs-WebAcl/4312a5d0-9878-4feb-a083-09d7a9cfcfbb",
      "DefaultAction":{
         "Allow":{
            
         }
      },
      "Description":"",
      "Rules":[
         {
            "Name":"AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet",
            "Priority":500,
            "Statement":{
               "ManagedRuleGroupStatement":{
                  "VendorName":"AWS",
                  "Name":"AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet"
               }
            },
            "OverrideAction":{
               "None":{
                  
               }
            },
            "VisibilityConfig":{
               "SampledRequestsEnabled":true,
               "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled":true,
               "MetricName":"AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to extract "*AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet*" from the section:-

> - ```
>       "Name":"AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet",
>        "Priority":500,
>        "Statement":{
>           "ManagedRuleGroupStatement":{
>              "VendorName":"AWS",
>              "Name":"AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet"*
>   ```

At the minute my code is returning a key error:

*KeyError: 'Rules[].Statement[].ManagedRuleGroupStatement[].Name'*

The format of this line is clearly wrong, but I don't know why.

> ruleset = y['Rules[].Statement[].ManagedRuleGroupStatement[].Name']

My code block:

> ```
>   respons = client.get_web_acl(Name=(acl),Scope='REGIONAL',Id=(ids))
>      for y in response['WebACLs']:
>      ruleset = y['Rules[].Statement[].ManagedRuleGroupStatement[].Name']
> ```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: can you print y and paste the response in your question? Your "ruleset = " line is clearly incorrect.

Comment: What is your expected output please?

Comment: Ive added the output of y above

Comment: The expected output is "AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet"

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :- In case anyone else comes up against this problem, I fixed this by doing it a slightly different way.

```
    #Requesting the info from AWS via get_web_acl request
    respons = client.get_web_acl(Name=(acl),Scope='REGIONAL',Id=(ids))
    
    #Converting the dict output to a string to make it searchable
    result = json.dumps(respons)

    #Defining what I want to search for
    fullstring = "AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet"

    #Searching the output & printing the result: if = true / else = false
    if fullstring in result:
        print("Found WAF ruleset: AWS-AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet!")
    else:
        print("WAF ruleset not found!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, as part of my research I found a cool thing called jello.
(https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jello).

jello is similar to jq in that it processes JSON and JSON Lines data except it uses standard python dict and list syntax.

So, I copied my json into a file called `file.json`

Ran `cat file.json | jello -s` to print a grep-able schema by using the -s option

Found the bit I was interested in - in my case the name of the `ManagedRuleGroupStatement` and ran the following:

```
cat file.json | jello -s _.WebACL.Rules[0].Statement.ManagedRuleGroupStatement.Name
```

This gave me exactly what I wanted!

It doesn't work inside a python script but was something new and interesting to learn!